# Android gRPC request throwing UNAVAILABLE exception

Tags: android, grpc

I am attempting to send a request from an android application to my laptop. This is currently resulting in the following exception being thrown.

```
Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.35 (port 8445) from /:: (port 55176): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:143)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:570)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:450)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250)
    at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:285)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$3.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:527)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    at libcore.io.Linux.connect(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:95)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:136)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:95)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:157)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:135)
    ... 15 more
}
```

I have confirmed that the IP and the port are correct. Below I have attached both the server proto file and the apps proto file, along with the execution from the app.

**Server Proto file**

```
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "bitbucket.org/bthreesoftware/restaurant-libs/proto/WaiterProto";

package WaiterProto;

service WaiterService {
  rpc UserLogin(LoginRequest) returns (LoginResponse) {}
  rpc GetMenuItems(MenuRequest) returns (MenuResponse) {}
}

message LoginRequest {
  string username = 1;
  string password = 2;
}

message LoginResponse {
  Restaurant restaurant = 1;
  User user = 2;
  string jwt = 3;
}

message User {
  int64 id = 1;
  int64 restaurantId = 2;
  string username = 3;
  string firstName = 4;
  string surname = 5;
  string password = 6;
  string lastLogin = 7;
}

message Restaurant {
  int64 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  string addressLineOne = 3;
  string addressLineTwo = 4;
  string postCode = 5;
  string contactNumber = 6;
  bool active = 7;
}

message MenuRequest {
  int64 restaurantId = 1;
}

message MenuResponse {
  int64 id = 1;
  int64 restaurantId = 2;
  string name = 3;
  repeated MenuItem menuItems = 4;
}

message MenuItem {
  int64 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  string description = 3;
  float price = 4;
}
```

**Apps Proto file**

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "uk.bthree.restaurant.WaiterProto";
option java_outer_classname = "WaiterProto";

option go_package = "bitbucket.org/bthreesoftware/restaurant-libs/proto/WaiterProto";

package WaiterProto;

service WaiterService {
  rpc UserLogin(LoginRequest) returns (LoginResponse) {}
  rpc GetMenuItems(MenuRequest) returns (MenuResponse) {}
}

message LoginRequest {
  string username = 1;
  string password = 2;
}

message LoginResponse {
  Restaurant restaurant = 1;
  User user = 2;
  string jwt = 3;
}

message User {
  int64 id = 1;
  int64 restaurantId = 2;
  string username = 3;
  string firstName = 4;
  string surname = 5;
  string password = 6;
  string lastLogin = 7;
}

message Restaurant {
  int64 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  string addressLineOne = 3;
  string addressLineTwo = 4;
  string postCode = 5;
  string contactNumber = 6;
  bool active = 7;
}

message MenuRequest {
  int64 restaurantId = 1;
}

message MenuResponse {
  int64 id = 1;
  int64 restaurantId = 2;
  string name = 3;
  repeated MenuItem menuItems = 4;
}

message MenuItem {
  int64 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  string description = 3;
  float price = 4;
}
```

**App execution**

```
fun runTask(vararg params: Void) {
        executor.execute {
            Log.i(TAG, "runTask: sending request")

            try {
                val channel: Channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("192.168.1.35", 8445).usePlaintext().build()
                val stub = WaiterServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel)

                val builder = LoginRequest.newBuilder()
                builder.username = this.username
                builder.password = this.password

                val request = builder.build()
                val response = stub.userLogin(request)

                val mobileSession: MobileSession = mapResponse(response)
                Log.i(TAG, "runTask: $mobileSession")
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "runTask: ${exception.message}")
            }

            handler.post {
                Log.i(TAG, "runTask: complete")
            }
        }
    }
```

**Android manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="uk.bthree.restaurant.waiter">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
                 android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
                 tools:targetApi="31"
                 android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_bthree_logo"
                 android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_bthree_logo_round"
                 android:supportsRtl="true"
                 android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
                  android:exported="true"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

I have attempted to run this on different ports. I have also dropped all firewalls on my laptop to rule out that.
I am also using android 23 and above for the app.

Comment: Try to connect to a web server or something on your laptop to verify connectivity is not the issue

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano, When running the web request; the following error is occurring: java.lang.Error: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 192.168.1.35 not permitted

Comment: After adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to the maifest, the web request worked. However this has not solved the grpc issue noted above.